# Use Pandas 'to_csv' to rapidly output multiple files by data contents

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split up samples within a large DataFrame and writing each to it's own .tsv file, and my current code does this, but slowly. Is there a good way to speed this task up in pandas?

```
for x in df.x.unique():
    temp = df[df.x==x]

    temp.to_csv(
        '{}.tsv'.format(x),
        sep='\t',
        index=False,)
```

Comment: `for x,d in df.groupby('x'): d.to_csv(f'{x}.tsv', sep='\t', index=False)`?

Comment: Excellent! This runs much faster, I appreciate the help.